# Reporting services configuration manager cannot find Report Server instance (SQL server 2008 R2 standard)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008, ssrs

I have SSRS and SQL server 2008 running on same server. However sometime I found Reporting services configuration manager cannot find Report Server instance and it is affecting reports.
The only way to resolve this is to reboot the server. This issue started happening after domain migration to a new domain.

Below is the error, I'm getting. Anyone, please help me. Many thanks!
[image: ssrs error]

Comment: In your SQL Server Configuration, do you have named pipes enabled?

Comment: You might also be better off asking this on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Named Pipes is disabled. Also I posted this question in dba.stackexchange.com now. Thanks

Comment: Here's a link to the question on dba. if anyone is interested >>> https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/284983/reporting-services-configuration-manager-cannot-find-report-server-instance-sql

Comment: @JitendraGupta ... Did anyone help you get this resolved by chance? I think I have an idea or two about what's going on here and how to further troubleshoot and potentially resolve. When you say you migrated to another domain, does that mean this server was joined to a different domain and you joined it to a new domain and the old one went away or how exactly did you migrate to the new domain? Have you tested to see if restarting the SSRS service also resolves the issue without a server reboot? See if `iisreset` command fixes it too or maybe both. Let me know about the migration.

Comment: No I didn't got any answer still. Yes earlier the server was joined to xx.com domain but now it is joined to yy.com domain then server was rebooted properly. At the time of issue, I also tried restarting SSRS services but it didn't resolved the issue. I had not tried IISreset.